# How can I install Cinelerra on Kubuntu?

Tags: package-management, software-sources, cinelerra

Hope s.o. can help me ....

According to a page I found I should do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

But that led to the problem that the package "libmpeg3cine" could not be installed because some files were already installed by package "mpeg3-utils". The package system seemed broken because of a defective package. So I tried to uninstall it - which did not work. It worked only by running `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status` and removing the "cinelerra" section.

Then I tried to compile it according to the [g-raffa compilation howto](http://www.g-raffa.eu/Cinelerra/HOWTO/compilation.html).

But this did not work until "make". Then I got the following errors:

```
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make[3]: *** [x264] Fehler 1
make[3]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/peterl/system/cinelerra-4.3/quicktime/thirdparty/x264.052906'
make[2]: *** [x86_64/x264] Fehler 2
make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/peterl/system/cinelerra-4.3/quicktime'
make[1]: *** [all] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/peterl/system/cinelerra-4.3'
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

I even tried the newer version but that stopped earlier I think with the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/libmpeg3.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.libs/libmpeg3.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libmpeg3hv.la] Fehler 1
make[3]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/peterl/system/cinelerra-cv-old/libmpeg3'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Fehler 1
make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/peterl/system/cinelerra-cv-old/libmpeg3'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/peterl/system/cinelerra-cv-old'
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

As far as I know it says that I have to recompile with "-fPIC"
So I tried to "configure" with:

```
./configure --with-buildinfo=git/recompile --enable-mmx --without-fpic --without-pic
```

But that seemed not to help as well. I also tried as mentioned with:

```
./configure --with-buildinfo=git/recompile
```

But that did not work as well.

Now I do not know what else I could try to get Cinelerra running.

Maybe there is another howto? Hope Someone can help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. My problem was that I had compiled ffmpeg and x264 before manualla and installed them. But I think that was not supported somehow.

After I uninstalled them and installed to official versions the problem disappeared and I was able to run "make" without errors.

Sorry for this question cuz the problem was selfmade.

Anyway thanks to all and esp. to Roland Taylor for editing my 1. Question here.

cu